# Not getting output from a subcircuit

Tags: logic-gates, proteus, subcircuit

I just started to working with Proteus, and I want to implement and test some simple circuits.
I made a subcircuit and tested it with logic state and logic probes.

The first picture is my main sheet, and the second picture is the circuit inside subcircuit.

Why don't I get any output from the bottom circuit while I do get output from the top circuit, since they are the same subcircuit?

[image]

[image: the subcircuit I made]

Comment: Are there any error messages ? If so please [edit] it into the question. The red colouring of the terminals probably indicate that there is some error. Try searching if any error message is there.

Comment: first thing that I see is that you may have chosen invalid pin names ... perhaps `a` is not `A` .... also, pay attention to the information in the status bar

Answer (score 1):

After digging in the program, I found out what was the problem.
There are two kinds of gates:
'AND' gate that is in 'ACTIVE' library
and 'AND_2' gate that is in 'DISMMDLS' (this also includes other gates).

I should have used the second kind of gates that are in the 'DISMMDLS' library.
I don't know why this happened, but this is the solution.